# Active Record LIMIT within GROUP_BY

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite, group-by

**SCENARIO**
I have a table full of posts with a users table.
I want to be able to fetch all the posts and group them by users but I want **to set a limit of say 10 per user.**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end

# I thought this might work but it just grabs the first 10 posts and groups them
Post.find(:all, :limit=>10).group_by(&:user)
```

Any thoughts? Do I have to write custom SQL for or can Active Record do this?

Comment: That limits the fetch to 10 for all users, not *per-user* as you're requesting. You might want to tag this with MySQL or whatever RDMBS you're using if it requires a specific SQL statement to work.

Comment: Ok thanks I added the sqlite3 tag to the post

Comment: I don't think this is DB-specific. ActiveRecord can handle this by itself. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Is your solution really fetching 10 per user. I posted some feedback below.

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
Post.group(:user_id).limit(10)
```

Comment: This isn't what I need the comment from tadman better illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. I'm hoping activerecord can do this and I can avoid writing any custom SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.group(:user_id).limit(10)
```

`group_by` is not a query method, but rather a method of Enumerable.

In your code, `Post.find(:all, :limit => 10)` is turned into an `Array` before being passed to `group_by`. The method above chains query methods together and only converts them to an `Array` when you need to use them.

ActiveRecord handles the whole thing. The above method translates to

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` GROUP BY user_id LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'm in the rails console trying this out and I don't see how this is working. I'm trying to return a hash that I can iterate to show a maximum of 10 posts per user.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to grab the recent 10 posts per user would require a nested sub-query (which can have performance issues) or postgres-style lateral join. Fairly confident this cannot be accomplished with only active-record and requires writing custom SQL, which you've indicated you want to avoid.

As an alternative that could be accomplished without custom SQL, you could list each user and their posts within a time window (e.g. past month or year) with the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recent_posts, -> { where(posts: {created_at 1.month.ago..Time.now}) }, class_name: 'Post'
end

User.includes(:recent_posts).each do |user|
  user.recent_posts
end
```

Which would not execute a SQL query for each user and would therefore be relatively performant compared with doing it purely in ruby.