# Rails limit each set of group using activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

My question is somewhat similar to this - [Active Record LIMIT within GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235903/active-record-limit-within-group-by)

**I want to limit the [ActiveSupport::OrderedHash](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash) to a specific count(100) for each site.**

The limit can be anything like 100 or 4

For simplicity I have considered it as 4

```
Session.website_only.during(date_range)
       .count(group: [:site_id, :referrer_host],
              order: 'count_all DESC',
              limit: 4)
```

The SQL query generated looks like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, site_id AS site_id,
referrer_host AS referrer_host FROM "sessions"
WHERE "sessions"."created_at" >= '2013-12-09 00:00:00.000000'
AND "sessions"."created_at" <= '2013-12-16 23:59:59.999999' AND
(referrer_host IS NOT NULL)
AND (("sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%google.com%'
AND "sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%yahoo.com%'
AND "sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%bing.com%' 
AND "sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%aol.com%')) 
AND (("sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%twitter.com%' 
AND "sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%facebook.com%' 
AND "sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%linkedin.com%' 
AND "sessions"."referrer_host" NOT ILIKE '%fb.me%')) 
GROUP BY "sessions"."site_id", "sessions"."referrer_host" 
ORDER BY count_all DESC LIMIT 4
```

Updated Question

---

**What I get**

A ActiveSupport::Ordered Hash that has counts from all sessions for a site grouped as `site_id` and `referrer_host`

This is an example of actual result, it has the grouped hash but limited on entire set, what I want is the grouping should be limited to 100 only.

```
{[1, "https"]=>8769, [1, "www.example.com"]=>2359, [1, "www.xyz.com"]=>1935, [1, "www.bayers.com"]=>379, 
[2, "www.ruby.com"]=>1322, [2, "www.employment.com"]=>472, [2, "https"]=>424, 
[3, "www.rails.com"]=>424, [3, "www.arizona.net"]=>392, [3, "www.murphy.com"]=>390, 
[4, "www.associates.com"]=>374, [4, "www.reddit.com"]=>365, [4, "www.razorshape.com"]=>352, 
[5, "www.rediff.com"]=>337, [5, "www.tumbleweed.com"]=>327, [5, "www.arizona.com"]=>289, 
[6, "https"]=>275, [131, "www.example.com"]=>253, [6, "www.murphy.com"]=>236, [6, "www.associates.com"]=>227}
```

**What I want**

Instead of each any number of sets within each group I want to restrict it to 4.

Comment: So, is this not doing what you need? What are you getting and what do you need?

Comment: I want to limit each group to a specific count(100) for each site. The current results limits the complete result set.

Comment: So, you only want groups that have over 100 results? Or what do you want to do with the results?

Comment: No I want the number of set returned for each to be restricted to 4

Comment: Do you want at most 4 results per each `site_id`?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want.
The limit of 4 is just an example, but my actual results are in thousands (1K). The limit may vary(its a defined macro).
Wasn't my question precise ? I thought it was. sorry if I confused

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do it in the database without calculating the values for all of the rows and then filtering. So in that case, I'd rather filter it in ruby, which makes the code clearer for reading. Something like this:

```
data = {[1, "https"]=>8769, [1, "www.example.com"]=>2359, [1, "www.xyz.com"]=>1935, [1, "www.bayers.com"]=>379, 
[2, "www.ruby.com"]=>1322, [2, "www.employment.com"]=>472, [2, "https"]=>424, 
[3, "www.rails.com"]=>424, [3, "www.arizona.net"]=>392, [3, "www.murphy.com"]=>390, 
[4, "www.associates.com"]=>374, [4, "www.reddit.com"]=>365, [4, "www.razorshape.com"]=>352, 
[5, "www.rediff.com"]=>337, [5, "www.tumbleweed.com"]=>327, [5, "www.arizona.com"]=>289, 
[6, "https"]=>275, [131, "www.example.com"]=>253, [6, "www.murphy.com"]=>236, [6, "www.associates.com"]=>227}

limit = 4  # or 100
#Create a hash that has arrays on the keys
counts = Hash.new(0)
result = Hash.new

data.each do |k, v|
  site = k[0]
  if counts[site] < limit
    counts[site]+=1
    result[k]=v
  end
end

puts counts
puts result
```

The final format of the `counts` structure is not exactly the same as that of the `data` structure, but it can easily be converted back. The running code can be found in http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/26fc3/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wont that slow down in case the complete set grows upto 50K ?. As it does right now, cause what am dealing with is a [Big data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) :)

Comment: Yes, it would be slow. Doing it in plain sql will probably be slow as well, as the query can't calculate this kind of "composite limit". So to do it in SQL, you would need to calculate it first, and then filter by joining the calculated table with itself and removing the necessary records. In general, if you're going to do Big data, there are better ways than just a plain sql query.

Comment: Agreed. I'll be looking for the query.